# MSSQL, PHP and Stored Procedures with multiple result sets

Tags: php, sql-server

I seem to be having a problem. I've inherited some PHP code which is running on a windows machine, which is connecting to a MSSQL DB on the same machine. Unfortunately, we're a Linux house and we need to now get this code running on a linux machine. So I'm in the throws of slowly going through it all and making the tweaks to make sure it runs correctly in Linux. The majority of changes has been catering for config settings that were C:\ rather than /var/www and variable checking.

I've hit a bit of a brick wall though. The code runs a query that returns a limited result for pagination.

The php code looks like this:

```
if ( $offset !== null ) {
  $querystring = "exec SSDEV.dbo.sp_limit '".str_replace("'", "''",$querystring)."', '".intval($offset)."','".intval($limit)."';";
}
```

The query string ends up looking like this:

```
exec SSDEV.dbo.sp_limit 'select  users.*  from users order by users.first_name asc', '0','20';
```

The query is run with the following line of code:

```
$result = mssql_query($querystring,$this->connection);
```

sp_limit reads like this:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

ALTER procedure sp_limit (@sql text, @offset int, @limit int)
as
declare @cursor int;

set @offset=@offset+1;
exec sp_cursoropen @cursor output, @sql, 8,8193;
exec sp_cursorfetch @cursor,32,@offset,@limit;
exec sp_cursorclose @cursor;

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Running the stored procedure in query analyzer, it runs with no problems, but I have noticed that it returns 2 result sets, one blank one (with column fields though) for sp_cursoropen and one from sp_cursorfetch, which contains the data I'm looking for.

If I comment out the line that creates the stored procedure query string in PHP and run just the basic SQL statement without the 'limit' on it, the code runs fine.

However, when it runs with the stored procedure, the page hangs forever and then fails on the the mssql_query() function. Here is the error from the apache logs:

```
[Wed Sep 26 09:26:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): Query failed in /var/www/mysite/libs/DB.class.php on line 80, referer: http://mysite/
[Wed Sep 26 09:26:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): Unable to set query in /var/www/mysite/libs/DB.class.php on line 80, referer: http://mysite/
[Wed Sep 26 09:26:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Query failed: Changed database context to 'SSDEV'.' in /var/www/mysite/libs/DB.class.php:82
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/mysite/libs/HTML.class.php(22): DB->select('select region_c...', 2, 1)
    #1 /var/www/mysite/controllers/SS_Users_Controller.class.php(264): HTML->get_select_query('select region_c...', 'region_code', 'region_name', 'fk_regions', '', ' a Region', Array)
    #2 /var/www/mysite/libs/Controller.class.php(72): SS_Users_Controller->index()
    #3 /var/www/mysite/index.php(34): Controller->execute()
    #4 {main}
       thrown in /var/www/sweetspot/libs/DB.class.php on line 82, referer: http://mysite/
[Wed Sep 26 09:26:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0, referer: http://mysite/
```

As you can see, it's having a problem executing the stored procedure. As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't be too much of a problem returning multiple result sets in PHP and handling it. If it was throwing the error when trying to access the result set, then I would have an easier time believing that its the fact that there are two result sets, but from my googling, I know that PHP shouldn't haven a problem with it, other than you need to use mssql_next_result(). What bugs me, is this works fine on the windows version, why is it suddenly a problem and why only the stored procedure and not normal SQL statements?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it possible the driver on Windows behaves different from the driver you use on *nix? That the former supports multiple resultsets, and the second doesn't?